# Python pypi proxy-checker output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I installed this python tool: https://pypi.org/project/proxy-checker/
And I also installed PycURL

And my code is

```
checker = ProxyChecker()
checker.check_proxy('202.138.248.72:43037')
```

And its says that all is working, but where can I see the results like at the link?
Do I have to link anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.check_proxy()` [returns](https://github.com/ricerati/proxy-checker-python/blob/9a036777c981814367a1000d94e161e6ef3b9c3b/proxy_checker/proxy_checker.py#L140) the result. You need to catch that and use in whatever way you want:

```
result = checker.check_proxy('202.138.248.72:43037')
```

For example, you can print the results:

```
print(results)
```

If you want just print and nothing else you can print directly:

```
print(checker.check_proxy('202.138.248.72:43037'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the result:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from proxy_checker import ProxyChecker


checker = ProxyChecker()
pprint(checker.check_proxy('202.138.248.72:43037'))
```

```
{'anonymity': 'Elite',
 'country': 'Indonesia',
 'country_code': 'ID',
 'protocols': ['socks4'],
 'timeout': 797}
```